# Create backup from database with query in ORM

Tags: sql-server, sql-query-store

How I can create a backup from my Sql database with sqlQuery or another methods (in ORM)?
actually I have this Query but I can't use that in ORM

Comment: Which ORM are use using?

Comment: You have... which query?  Do you have something and are getting an error?  Post code that you are having a problem with and the error you receive.  And yes, which ORM?  Most (that is, any decent ones) will let you run ad-hoc statements which should let you run a backup assuming you have the permissions to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`BACKUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
--Backing Up a Whole Database   
BACKUP DATABASE { database_name | @database_name_var }   
  TO <backup_device> [ ,...n ]   
  [ <MIRROR TO clause> ] [ next-mirror-to ]  
  [ WITH { DIFFERENTIAL 
           | <general_WITH_options> [ ,...n ] } ]  
[;]
```